# Javascript canvas one shadow with different strokeStyle

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to have one shadow for a large number of dots that over lap with different strokeStyles. I don't want to see the shadow on top of the other dots. So is there a way to have different strokeStyles for one path, or is there a way to apply one shadow to multiple paths?
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cwtisme/rj0frpo4/)

```js
     var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
     ctx.shadowColor = "black";
     ctx.shadowBlur = 10;
     ctx.lineWidth = 30;
     ctx.lineCap = 'round';

      //This is how I want the shadow to appear
     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.moveTo(50, 50);
     ctx.lineTo(50, 50);
     ctx.moveTo(70, 50);
     ctx.lineTo(70, 50);
     ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
     ctx.stroke();

      //But I want to have different strokeStyle.
      //And I don't want the shadow on top the other dot
     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.moveTo(50, 100);
     ctx.lineTo(50, 100);
     ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
     ctx.stroke();

     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.moveTo(70, 100);
     ctx.lineTo(70, 100);
     ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
     ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
```